# Why rails devise gem throws 'invalid current password' error if only password confirmation is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords, renewal

I'm dealing with the renewal password screen errors on my rails app which has three inputs: `current password`, `new password` and `password confirmation`.

There is one case when `current password` is correct but `new password` and `password confirmation` are blank but devise still throws 2 errors:

- Current password is invalid. (wrong)
- New password can't be blank. (correct)

Have anyone experienced this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess your **`current_password`** is **not** correct. Any typos?

Let's update your password and test again!

```
user.password = new_password
user.password_confirmation = new_password
user.save
```